# Why am I receiving a "Posts validation failed" error when I am sending a POST to my API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have form that I would like to be able to POST its content to my MongoDB server that I have connected on the backend, however when I do POST I get the error "Posts validation failed: post: Cast to string failed for value "{}" at path "post" and I have no idea why. I just started with react so forgive me if the solution is something simple.

This is my form page:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PostList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        post: '',
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ post: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const post = {
            post: this.state.name
        };

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/posts', { post })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="flex-container-home">
                <div className="app">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>
                            Post:
                        <input type="text" name="post" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is my router:

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const Post = require('../models/posts')

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        post: req.body.post,
    });
    try {
        const savedPost = await post.save()
        res.json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

This is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    post: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema)
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the source of the problem, but you need to pass a configuration option to axios post request like `axios.post(url, data, config)`  where config can be defined as `let config={headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}}`.

Comment: I just added this, but my issue is still there. Thanks though @BlackMath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `{ post }` with `post`,
`{ post }` will give

```
{
   post: {
      post: this.state.name
   }
}
```

Expected might be

```
{
   post: this.state.name
}
```

Comment: I replaced it with that but got the error "Posts validation failed: post: Path `post` is required."

Comment: when I use postman I can properly send a post to my db, so I think it is receiving it correctly. Sorry if I'm not answering your question as you intended

Comment: checkout the network tab on browser, what data its posting

Comment: there is 2 post. The first one when I click on it says failed to load response data. The second one reads " message: {errors: {post: {name: "ValidatorError", message: "Path `post` is required.",…}},…}} "

Comment: Its response, check your request body

Comment: kind: "string"
path: "post"
reason: null
stringValue: ""{}""        (this is the response body that appears on console when I inspect element)

Comment: `post: this.state.name` this must be `post: this.state.post` right?

Comment: okay, missing `body-parser`. add `const bodyParser = require("body-parser");app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: I did this and I am now able to see "kind: "string"
path: "post"
reason: null
stringValue: ""{ post: 'hi' }"" " , but the main message still reads " message: "Posts validation failed: post: Cast to string failed for value "{ post: 'hi' }" at path "post""
 "

Comment: where should I add the body parser?

Comment: changed `{ post }` to `post`?